# Send utf8 character with retrofit as query parameter

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

How can I send non-ascii characters as a query parameter
without encoding it as ascii with retrofit (assuming thats whats happening)?

For example I dont want the value of the query `q` to go from `/?q=Gä` to `/?q=G%C3%A4` when it arrives at the server end.

```
@GET("endpoint/")
fun get(
    @Query("q") value: String,
): Response
```

I have tried using `@Query(value = "q", encoded=true)` though I dont think that does what I initially thought it would.

I also want to mention that I can send this request in my firefox browser and it works correctly.

- [Non-ASCII Header Encoding Issues #891](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/891) (though about the header)